# Could you please help me to understand an R code?

Tags: r, function, matrix, lapply, cbind

I'm completely new to R. Would you please explain me the following code? Thank you a lot in advance.

```
patterns <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),4,3, byrow = T)
input <- unlist(lapply(1:100, function(i) {
    ps <- patterns[sample(nrow(patterns)),]
    as.vector(t(ps))
}))
teach <- c(input[-1],input[1])
data <- cbind(input, teach)
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? If it's literally every line, I suggest you start with a basic R tutorial (maybe [An Introduction To R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)). To see the help page for any command, you can type `?matrix` in R to bring up the help for that particular function.

Comment: Thank you so much. For instance, what is the function of this line: c(input[-1],input[1])

Comment: If that's your specific question, please update your post to indicate that. Then others can post an answer down below and you can accept a "correct" answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in general,

```
var <- expr
```

evaluates the R expression *expr* and assigns the result to the variable *var*. If the statement occurs inside a function, then *var* becomes a function-local variable, otherwise, it becomes a global variable.

```
c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0)
```

Combines 12 `double` literals into a `double` vector in the order given.

```
matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),4,3, byrow=T )
```

Creates a `matrix` from the vector with 4 rows and 3 columns, populating the matrix one row at a time from top to bottom (left-to-right within each row).

```
nrow(patterns)
```

Returns the number of rows in the `patterns` matrix.

```
sample(nrow(patterns))
```

Returns an `integer` vector of `nrow(patterns)` elements, by basically randomly scrambling the set of integers from 1 to `nrow(patterns)`.

```
patterns[sample(nrow(patterns)),]
```

Indexes the `patterns` matrix. This type of indexing basically allows you to extract a "submatrix" of the original matrix. The argument to the left of the comma specifies the rows to select, and to the right specifies the columns to select. An omitted argument is equivalent to specifying all indexes of that dimension. This particular expression selects all rows and all columns in the matrix, but scrambles the row order.

```
t(ps)
```

Transposes the matrix `ps`.

```
as.vector(t(ps))
```

Flattens the transposed matrix into a vector. Note that this is by column, which is the opposite of how the matrix was originally constructed from a vector earlier. Note that, because this is the last statement in the enclosing function, it will automatically become the return value of the function when it is executed.

```
function(i) {
    ps <- patterns[sample(nrow(patterns)),]
    as.vector(t(ps))
}
```

Defines a function taking one parameter `i` and that executes the two statements I explained above. Note that `patterns` is effectively closured by this function.

```
1:100
```

Creates an `integer` vector consisting of 100 elements, the integers from 1 to 100.

```
lapply(1:100, function(i) { ... } )
```

Executes the function given in the second argument once for each element of the first argument, passing the element as the first argument of the function when it is called for that particular element. In this case, the result is the function will be executed 100 times, passing integers 1 to 100 as the argument to the `i` parameter for each respective invocation. `lapply()` always returns the return value of every single execution of the function, combined into a `list` object.

```
unlist( ... )
```

Converts the `list` into a single homogenous (non-list) object. How this works depends on the exact nature of its argument, but in this case, it will combine the vectors returned by every function invocation into a single vector.

```
input[-1]
```

Returns the entire vector `input` excluding its first element.

```
input[1]
```

Returns the first element of the vector `input`.

```
c(input[-1],input[1])
```

Combines the two previous values. The end result is the first element has been moved to the end of the vector.

```
cbind(input, teach)
```

Performs a "column-bind" of the two aforementioned vectors. This means each vector will be treated as an `length(vector)`-by-1 matrix, and the two matrices will be combined into a `length(vector)`-by-2 matrix. (If the lengths weren't equal, the function would still succeed, but it would recycle any short vector inputs and print a warning message.)

Answer (score -3):

```
lmepair.df <- function(fixed, dataframe, name.ID, num.outcomes, method="REML", random.indep=F, random.group=NULL, use.lmer=F, group.weights=NULL, null.model=NULL, return.matrices=F, loglik.only=F, eigen.loglik.only=F, return.sigma=F, score=F, return.loglikfn=F){
  require(MASS)
  if (use.lmer==F)
    require(assist) # also loads nlme #
  else
    require(lme4)
```